# Automate AssemblyFileVersion Incrementation using GIT

Tags: vb.net, git, version-control, versioning, .net-assembly

Ok I understand that this is probably not conventional, but that aside: I am using the AssemblyFileVersion as kind of my "Build Name" string.  It is formated like this:

```
' File Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'      Year
'      Month 
'      Day
'      Commit Number for that day
'
' Build Name can either be alpha | beta | hotfix | release
' alpha - is a development buildname with rapid changing API
' beta - is a production build for our beta users
' hotfix - is a production version with a bug fix
' release - is a standard issue production version.

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.8.3")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("13.10.24.3")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyBuildName("alpha")>
```

Unfourtunately I am having to adjust the AssemblyInfo.vb **EVERY TIME** I do a git commit.  Now I know GIT actually stores the commits in like a log file several places in the .git directory.  My question is: is there anyway to automate this file to read from the git files to see what the year/month/day/commit#ForThatDay and automatically adjust the AssemblyFileVersion (or even a custom Assembly Attribute)?

Comment: You'll probably want to pre-commit hook of some sort. Not duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12890755/945456

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) in order to get an id representing the tag/SHA1 of the current commit, and integrate it in your Assembly file.

```
v1.0-2-g2414721-DEV
 ^   ^  ^       ^
 |   |  |       \-- if a dirtyMarker was given, it will appear here if the repository is in "dirty" state
 |   |  \---------- the "g" prefixed commit id. The prefix is compatible with what git-describe would return - weird, but true.
 |   \------------- the number of commits away from the found tag. So "2414721" is 2 commits ahead of "v1.0", in this example.
 \----------------- the "nearest" tag, to the mentioned commit.
```

It is similar to "[Automatically versioning Android project from git describe with Android Studio/Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021756/6309)", but to be adapted to vb.net.
Or you can have "[fake revision number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875137/6309)".

For a more complete build Assembly file generation, see [that maven plugin "**`maven-git-commit-id-plugin`**"](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) (again, to be adapted to a vb.net build).
It can generate a file as complete as:

```
{
     "branch" : "testing-maven-git-plugin",
     "describe" : "v2.1.0-2-g2346463",
     "commitTime" : "06.01.1970 @ 16:16:26 CET",
     "commitId" : "787e39f61f99110e74deed68ab9093088d64b969",
     "commitIdAbbrev" : "787e39f",
     "commitUserName" : "Konrad Malawski",
     "commitUserEmail" : "konrad.malawski@java.pl",
     "commitMessageFull" : "releasing my fun plugin :-)
                            + fixed some typos
                            + cleaned up directory structure
                            + added license etc",
     "commitMessageShort" : "releasing my fun plugin :-)",
     "buildTime" : "06.01.1970 @ 16:17:53 CET",
     "buildUserName" : "Konrad Malawski",
     "buildUserEmail" : "konrad.malawski@java.pl"
 }
```

That illustrates how you can ask the git repo for all kind of different information (not just the date, but the branch, committer, commit message, ...).
See the [`DescribeCommand.java`](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/project13/jgit/DescribeCommand.java) for more details on the implementation.